# heroku failing to process requirements.txt "because these package versions have conflicting dependencies."

Tags: django, heroku, pip, pyyaml, chatterbot

I have deployed this project many times before successfully and have made no changes to the requirements.txt file located in the root directory of the project, however.

Heroku will no longer accept the same requirements.txt file citing a dependency issue

Heroku still opens the last valid deployment to allow me to "”heroku run “pip freeze"

Deployed heroku requirements.txt

```
appnope==0.1.2
asgiref==3.4.1
backcall==0.2.0
backports.entry-points-selectable==1.1.0
blis==0.7.4
catalogue==2.0.6
certifi==2021.5.30
charset-normalizer==2.0.4
ChatterBot==1.0.4
chatterbot-corpus==1.2.0
click==8.0.1
colorgram.py==1.2.0
cymem==2.0.5
debugpy==1.4.3
decorator==5.1.0
distlib==0.3.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==3.2.8
django-filter==2.4.0
django-heroku==0.0.0
django-simple-chatbot==0.0.9
django-widget-tweaks==1.4.8
djangorestframework==3.12.4
en-core-web-sm @ https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0/en_core_web_sm-3.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
entrypoints==0.3
filelock==3.3.0
future==0.18.2
greenlet==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.1.0
heroku==0.1.4
httpie==2.4.0
huggingface-hub==0.0.12
idna==3.2
ipykernel==6.4.1
ipython==7.28.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
jedi==0.18.0
Jinja2==3.0.1
joblib==1.0.1
jupyter-client==7.0.3
jupyter-core==4.8.1
line-bot-sdk==1.20.0
MarkupSafe==2.0.1
mathparse==0.1.2
matplotlib-inline==0.1.3
murmurhash==1.0.5
nest-asyncio==1.5.1
nltk==3.6.2
numpy==1.21.2
packaging==21.0
parso==0.8.2
pathy==0.6.0
pexpect==4.8.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
Pillow==8.3.2
Pint==0.17
pipenv==2021.5.29
platformdirs==2.4.0
preshed==3.0.5
print==1.3.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.20
psycopg==3.0b1
psycopg2==2.9.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
ptyprocess==0.7.0
pydantic==1.8.2
Pygments==2.10.0
pymongo==3.12.0
pyparsing==2.4.7
PySocks==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.7.5
pytz==2021.3
PyYAML==5.4.1
pyzmq==22.3.0
regex==2021.8.28
requests==2.26.0
requests-toolbelt==0.9.1
sacremoses==0.0.46
six==1.16.0
smart-open==5.2.1
spacy==3.1.3
spacy-alignments==0.8.3
spacy-legacy==3.0.8
spacy-transformers==1.0.6
SQLAlchemy==1.2.19
sqlparse==0.4.2
srsly==2.4.1
textblob==0.15.3
thinc==8.0.10
tokenizers==0.10.3
torch==1.8.1+cpu
torchvision==0.9.1+cpu
tornado==6.1
tqdm==4.62.2
traitlets==5.1.0
transformers==4.9.2
turtle==0.0.1
typer==0.4.0
typing-extensions==3.10.0.2
urllib3==1.26.6
virtualenv==20.8.1
virtualenv-clone==0.5.7
wasabi==0.8.2
```

heroku now tells me the following error when i try to deploy my latest version using identical requirements.txt files.

```
 The conflict is caused by:
           The user requested PyYAML==5.4.1
           chatterbot-corpus 1.2.0 depends on PyYAML<4.0 and >=3.12
       
       To fix this you could try to:
       1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
       2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict
       
       ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

loosening the version or removing them entirely does not solve the issue.

is there a way i can deploy the app using something like

`-r requirements.txt -no dependencies`

It has melted my brain trying to resolve where this issue had arose from, as I had recently been using and updating (pushing via GitHub) the app without problem.

I have checked the GitHub push documents, rolled back the only change made to my app, and still the error with dependencies is present.

Has heroku cleared a cache for me or made an update in the way dependencies are used? I’m in a total quandary.

thank you in advance for any insight given.

Comment: is there a reason you can't use PyYAML < 4.0? You said you can't loosen the version, but I dont understand why that error message would still be there if you specified a compatible version that chatterbot requires

Comment: Thank you.  There were multiple dependency issues, so as i loosened, others displayed themselves, python-time-and-date was affecting everything. After some experimentation and a lot of failure. Removing all non essential dependencies and using a different runtime version of python in Heroku (python 3.7) solved my issues enough to loosen the remaining compatibility problems.
Also, pip was recently updated on Heroku and this was the reason for the tightening of validating compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible:

On Python 3, pip now uses its new dependency resolver, which is by design more strict.

Dependency versions are now fully validated during installation and the pip install step will fail with a ResolutionImpossible error if dependency conflicts are found.(https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/2288)

Use this buildpack on heroku to continue using your previous version of pip:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git#v201